# Print contents of a Map<String,List<Bean>> in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I've a map in which I'm storing an Id as a Key and under that Id I've a List of bean class where in all the bean properties are set and stored. How do I display the contents of the map in my java class? I tried something like this but not getting the list values.

```
for (Entry<String, List<MyBean>> me : MyForm.getClientId().entrySet()) 
{
  String key = me.getKey();
  List<MyBean> valueList = me.getValue();
  System.out.println(" Key: " + key);
  System.out.print("Values: ");
  for (MyBean s : valueList) {
    System.out.println(" " + s.getFundId());//This comes as null even though there are values in the list
  }
}
```

Similarly I want to print the contents on the jsp page. How do I do that?

Comment: Only debug can help you out.

Comment: May be value of your bean property is `null` value.

Comment: I think you checked value of `s` and you are printing its `FundId` which might be null.

Comment: The FundId is not null. I'm seperately printing the list values before inserting and it's fine. Could you tell me a way to print the values within map?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

Set your result map in as request attribute in Servlet as show below

```
    request.setAttribute("myMap", map);
    RequestDispatcher des = request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp");
    des.forward(request, response);
```

You may used different method to pass value to JSP page.

Than after you can use [JSTL Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/) to read that value in JSP page.

You need to include [jstl jar file](http://search.maven.org/#browse|707331597) into your class path and add below line to jsp to add tag library in page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Used this code in JSP when you required to read value

```
<c:forEach var="beanList" items="${myMap}">
    <c:forEach var="bean" items="${beanList['value']}">
        <c:out value="${bean.fundId}"></c:out>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Where `fundId` is your bean property name.

May this will help you.

Comment: Will try it out. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :-

Put this in your servlet/Controller class:- 
`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.setAttribute("myFormEntrySet",`

And these lines in your jsp page:-

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
MyForm.getClientId().entrySet());

<c:forEach var="myFormEntrySetVar" items="${myFormEntrySet}">
    <c:set var="myBeanList" value="${myFormEntrySetVar.value}" />  
    <c:forEach var="myBeanListVar" items="${myBeanList}" >
        ${myBeanListVar}
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

To use JSTL please download the jar of JSTL

Comment: Will try it out. Thanks for the response.